# Error decoding JSON files when script is running

Tags: python-3.x

**The Problem:**

I am very new to Python and keep running into the following error when running the code below. It will run fine the first time, but then every subsequent try receives this error:

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

**The Goal:**

We are using Amazon Transcribe to transcribe radio transmissions, which outputs a JSON file, containing the transcribed radio transmission. When that JSON file is downloaded back to a local drive, we want to run a script that watches for the file creation, grabs the transcribed text and appends it to a excel file with the current date. If that excel file doesn't exist, we want it to create the excel file, this should happen on the first transmission of every day. This script would run on a continuous loop, every day.

Also, any other critiques or suggestions would be appreciated.

**The Code:**

```
## Imports
import time
import json
import threading
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from typing import Union
import pandas as pd
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler, DirCreatedEvent, FileCreatedEvent
from watchdog.observers import Observer

####################################################################################

## Format date and time string and set variables
now = datetime.now()
year = now.strftime("%Y")
month = now.strftime("%m")
day = now.strftime("%d")

dt_string = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
dt_string_filename = now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H-%M-%S")

## Daily filename
daily_file = ("D:/AWS Transcribe/2 Daily Transcriptions/{}-{}-{}.xlsx".format(month, day, year))

####################################################################################

class CustomHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    """Custom handler for Watchdog"""

    def __init__(self):
        # List to store path
        self.path_strings = []

    # callback for File/Directory created event, called by Observer.
    def on_created(self, event: Union[DirCreatedEvent, FileCreatedEvent]):
        print(f"Event type: {event.event_type}\nAt: {event.src_path}")

        # check if it's File creation, not Directory creation
        if isinstance(event, FileCreatedEvent):
            # if so, do something with event.src_path - it's path of the created file.
            self.path_strings.append(event.src_path)
            print(f"Path content: \n{self.path_strings}")

            ## Open JOSN File and Convert to DataFrame, then extract the transcription.
            with open(event.src_path, 'r') as file:
                data = json.load(file)
                df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='columns')
                transcript = (df1.iloc[3]['results'])
                ## Use to test what is being read from JSON File
                #df1.to_excel("D:/Test Output.xlsx", index=False)
                file.close()

            ## Create new DataFrame with Date, Time & Transcript
            transcript_dict = {'Date & Time':[dt_string],'Radio Transmission':[transcript]}
            data1 = pd.DataFrame(transcript_dict)
            print(data1)

            ## Try to load the daily file, if it exists, then append the data, otherwise create a new daily excel file.
            try: 
                book = load_workbook(daily_file)
                with pd.ExcelWriter(daily_file, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
                    writer.book = book
                    data1.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=writer.sheets['Sheet1'].max_row)
                    writer.save()
                    writer.close()
                    print(f"Completed Appending To Daily File:\n{self.path_strings}")

            except IOError:
                ## Write new data frame to excel
                data1.to_excel(daily_file, index=False)
                print("Completed Creating Daily File: \n{}".format(daily_file))


def main():
    # Set the specific path to monitor
    path_to_monitor = "D:/AWS Transcribe/1 JSON From AWS/"

    # Create instance of observer and CustomHandler
    observer = Observer()
    handler = CustomHandler()

    # Start observer, checks only for .txt files recursively in the specified path
    observer.schedule(handler, path=path_to_monitor, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Waiting on next file...")
            #print(f"Current Daily File: \n{daily_file}")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Sample JSON Output from AWS Transcribe**

```
{"jobName":"88252321964544_39226.wav","accountId":"redacted","results":{"language_code":"en-US","transcripts":[{"transcript":"All right. That's clear. Two off."}],"language_identification":[{"score":"1","code":"en-US"},{"score":"0.0001","code":"en-IN"}],"items":[{"start_time":"0.409","end_time":"0.68","alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.837","content":"All"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"start_time":"0.689","end_time":"0.86","alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.892","content":"right"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.0","content":"."}],"type":"punctuation"},{"start_time":"0.87","end_time":"1.059","alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.505","content":"That's"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"start_time":"1.07","end_time":"1.45","alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.995","content":"clear"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.0","content":"."}],"type":"punctuation"},{"start_time":"1.46","end_time":"1.659","alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.987","content":"Two"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"start_time":"1.669","end_time":"2.18","alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.995","content":"off"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.0","content":"."}],"type":"punctuation"}]},"status":"COMPLETED"}
```

**Specific key we want from the JSON**

{"transcript":"All right. That's clear. Two off."}

Comment: Try adding an encoding to your call to `open()` something like `open(event.src_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`.

Comment: Error indicates the file is probably empty. I'm fuzzy on windows filesystems and `watchdog`, but I would suspect `on_created` might just be causing a race condition here; creation of the file doesn't mean the actual data of the file has finished writing yet. I'm not sure there even is an event you can use to detect this on windows. Best i can think of is to add some delay before reading (very fragile).

Comment: @MikaelÖhman, Thanks for the suggestion. I wondered if a delay would be necessary as well. I will give that a try!

Comment: @JonSG, I implemented your suggestion, it can't hurt to specify the encoding.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman, adding time.sleep() into the code did the trick! The code works flawlessly now. Thanks for the help!